# How To publish swf file using flash builder 4.5 flex project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mxml

I have a set of fla files templates that produce games and activities by changing its input XML file, What I want to do is to create xml editor in flex and by converting the fla files to actionscript projects in flex use the resulting xml to publish one swf.

in short my approach is
convert the games in flash to flex MXML components
modify the game data by passing XML argument to the MXMl components
click publish and the user can get the game as SWF

the goal is produce something similar to [this](https://www.onlinetrainingtemplates.com/editor/)

Is that possible??

Comment: It might be possible. Why not. If configuration XML file is to be used as an embedded resource during game SWF compilation, you would probably need to use MXMLC command line compiler on the server side http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcc.html

Comment: thank You, I'll try to search more on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy and straightforward way to reuse games and activities from flash professional
is to load the swf files to flex using swf loader then convert to movieclip using
swf.content = M as movieclip
next step is to modify the xml variable by M.XMLVar = xml
now I have modified version of the activity Im still looking for a way to convert the movieclip back to swf and save